# Is it possible to create a StructField of tuple type using PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I need to create a schema for a dataframe in Spark. I have no problem creating regular `StructFields`, such as `StringType`, `IntegerType`. However, I want to create a `StructField` for a tuple.

I have tried the following:

```
StructType([
             StructField("dst_ip", StringType()),
             StructField("port", StringType())
           ])
```

However, it throws an error

> "list object has no attribute 'name'"

Is it possible to create a StructField for a tuple type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `StructType` inside of a `StructField`:

```python
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(
            "myTuple",
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField("dst_ip", StringType()),
                    StructField("port", StringType())
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([], schema)
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- myTuple: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- dst_ip: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- port: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class [`StructType`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=types#pyspark.sql.types.StructType)--used to to define the structure of a DataFrame--is the data type representing a `Row` and it consists of a **list** of [`StructField`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=types#pyspark.sql.types.StructField)'s.

In order to define a tuple datatype for a column (say `columnA`) you need to encapsulate (list) the `StructType`'s of the the tuple's elements into a `StructField`. Note that `StructField`s need to have names since they represent columns.

Define tuple `StructField` as a new `StructType`:

```
columnA = StructField('columnA', StructType([
                                              StructField("dst_ip", StringType()),
                                              StructField("port", StringType())
                                             ])
                     )
```

Define schema containing `columnA` and `columnB` (of type `FloatType`):

```
mySchema = StructType([ columnA, StructField("columnB", FloatType())])
```

Apply schema to dataframe:

```
data =[{'columnA': ('x', 'y'), 'columnB': 1.0}] 
# data = [Row(columnA=('x', 'y'), columnB=1.0)] (needs from pyspark.sql import Row)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, mySchema)
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- columnA: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- dst_ip: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- port: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- columnB: float (nullable = true)
```

Show dataframe:

```
df.show()                                                                                 
# +-------+-------+
# |columnA|columnB|
# +-------+-------+
# | [x, y]|    1.0|
# +-------+-------+
```

(this is just the longer version of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49947632/2314737))